# use ios elements in flash cs5 on windows 7

Tags: ios, flash-cs5

I prepare to make a iphone application using flash cs5 on windows 7.

my question is how to use ios ui elements input, scroll, keyboard, select, options, on off etc in flash cs5

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any sdk other than Xcode you have to add the gui elements manually.

Here you are : [iOS6 GUI PSD](http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-6-gui-psd-iphone-5/)